# Не передается putSeriazable и putParcelable

Tags: android-sdk, android

Добрый день!

Существует следующая задача: необходимо передать два класса в другой активити. Классы Serializable и Parcelable.

```
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PromoQrActivity_.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable("promoAppParcel", promoAppParcel);
            args.putSerializable("pInf", (Serializable) pInf);
            i.putExtra("bundle", args);
```

а так же, пробовал вот так:

```
i.putExtra("promoAppParcel", promoAppParcel);
i.putExtra("pInf", (Serializable) pInf);
```

Обьекты передаваемые - **инициализированны и существуют**

Однако, когда я пытаюсь считать их в другой активити, в той в которую шла передача. Я получаю null. Считывание происходит вот так:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
    PromoInfo pInf = (PromoInfo) bundle.getSerializable("pInf");
```

При передаче не через Bundle а через Intent, считываю так же через Intent.

**Вопрос: почему я не могу считать обьекты в активити из Intent.**

Уточнение:

1. В проекте использован Android Annotations, пробовал получить обьект через [@Extra](/users/12151/extraenough), не помогло, по прежнему null.
2. Активити запускается из фрагмента, т.е. StartActivity происходит из Fragment, может быть тут еще что то спряталось.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер!

В общем, решил я свою проблему. Поделюсь решением с общественностью :)

Когда случается такая "магия", первым делом нужно бежать в класс Parcel, потому, что именно в нем собака зарыта. Дело в том, что любое свойство класса будь то просто String или Serializable класс должен быть обьявлено в **writeToParcel** и конструкторе класса **public PromoAppParcel(Parcel in)**

Только после этого, поля Parcelable класса не будут теряться при "гулянии по активити"

Приведу пример:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.countUserActivationsInTheDay);
    dest.writeString(this.applicationName);
    dest.writeString(this.companyName);
    dest.writeSerializable(this.pInf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Передаем так:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PromoQrActivity_.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();            
args.putParcelable("promoAppParcel", promoAppParcel);
args.putSerializable("pInf", (Serializable) pInf);
i.putExtras(args);
```

Получаем так:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
PromoInfo pInf = (PromoInfo) bundle.getSerializable("pInf");
```

Смысл в том, что с интентом передается непоименованный `Bundle` и его же надо вытащить на месте. В `Bundle` собсно говоря все и пакуется.

Comment: так тоже делал. не работает. Написал к вопросу уточнение, обратите на него внимание

Comment: А получаете вы его где в `onCreate()`?

Comment: В данный момент в методе void afterViews(), до этого, да, в onCreate. Но покопав исходники генерируемого класса (annotations) пришел к выводу, что afterViews вызывается в onCreate

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике содержимое `extras`. 

P.S. Вообще то рекомендуется имена экстрасов формировать в виде: `com.mydomain.mypackage.MyExtra` - хотя и не думаю, что проблема в этом.